# If the increment of a function is directly proportional to the increment of its argument, then it's an affine function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I know how to prove that the increment of an affine function is directly proportional to the increment of its argument. I would like to know how to prove (or see the validity of) the converse.

Maybe this is a proof (? I don't know):

Hypothesis: $f(x)-f(x_0)=k(x-x_0)$

Conclusion: $f(x)$ is of the form $f(x)=ax+b$

Proof: $f(x)=f(x_0)+k(x-x_0)=f(x_0)+kx-kx_0$

and since $f(x_0)$ and $kx_0$ are constants, this is of the form $f(x)=ax+b$

Is this proof correct? The problem is that it's just manipulation, I don't get an idea from it... Is there a more conceptual manner of seeing it?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Yes. You could take $ x_0=0$.

Comment: ...and then say $f(x) = ax+b$ where $b$ is the $y$-intercept $f(0)$ and $a=k$ is the slope.  Is that "more conceptual"?

Comment: @GEdgar: yes, thank you.